# Number of embeddings of $\mathbb Q (\alpha)$ into $\mathbb C$ which map $\beta \in \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ to a given conjugate

Tags: field-theory

I'm looking at a proof of the following:

> Let $K = \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\beta \in K$ with minimal polynomial $g \in \mathbb Q[X]$, where the roots of $g$ are $\beta_1, \ldots , \beta_m$. Then $d_i = |\{\sigma : K \hookrightarrow \mathbb C \ | \ \sigma(\beta) = \beta_i \}|$ is independent of $i$.

The proof starts by considering $h$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q(\beta)$, and says that $d_i \leq \mathrm{deg}(h) = [\mathbb Q(\alpha) : \mathbb Q (\beta)]$.

Why is this true? I did understand this at one point...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call $f_i$ the composition $\mathbb Q(\beta) \to  \mathbb Q(\beta_i) \to \mathbb C$, where the first morphism is the one sending $\beta$ to $\beta_i$ and the second  is the inclusion.
Then $d_i$ is the number of extensions of $f_i$ to $K$ , which is by definition  the separable degree  $[K:\mathbb Q(\beta)]_{sep}$ (cf. Lang *Algebra*, Chap.5, §4). So we have $d_i=[K:\mathbb Q(\beta)]_{sep}$.

But that separable degree $d_i=[K:\mathbb Q(\beta)]_{sep}$ is equal to the plain  degree  $[K : \mathbb Q (\beta)]$ because we are in characteristic zero. So that $d_i=[K : \mathbb Q (\beta)]$, which is indeed  independent of $i$ .

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out - hopefully someone will let me know if this is wrong.

Given a conjugate $\beta_j$ of $\beta$, we want to consider $d_j$, the number of embeddings $\sigma : \mathbb Q(\alpha) \hookrightarrow \mathbb C$ such that $\sigma(\beta) = \beta_j$. If $h$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q(\beta)$, then denote $h_\sigma$ the image of $h$ under $\sigma$. Since $\sigma$ is a homomorphism, it must map $\alpha$ to a root of $h_\sigma$. There are at most $\mathrm{deg}(h)$ such roots, and each unique root gives rise to a different embedding.

Comment: Looks good to me. Note that you really do have an equality $d_i = \deg h$ here. (In characteristic zero, everything is [separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension).)